# Finite element method - basis functions for triangular mesh

Tags: numerical-methods

In FEM, with a triangular mesh over $R^2$, could $\phi\left(x\right)=x_1\cdot\left[x\in T\right]$ be a basis function for the triangle $T$ with vertices in $\left(0,0\right), \left(0,1\right), \left(1,0\right)$? My doubts come from the fact it is not contiuous, $\phi\left(\left(1,0\right)\right)=1$ but $\phi\left(\left(1+\epsilon,0\right)\right)=0\ for\ \epsilon>0$.

**Edit:** basis of the trial space.

**Edit:** I forgot to add I want piecewise linear trial space, so the the question pretty much is about a convenient basis for it.

Comment: What does the notation $x_1\cdot\left[x\in T\right]$ mean? What is $x_1$? What does the bracket mean? Are you taking a dot product?

Comment: It means $x_1$ when $x\in T$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @J.D.: I suspect it's the [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

Comment: A basis function for what? Sure it could be a basis function, but one that might have bad properties in some circumstances -- it depends on how you want to use it.

Comment: Wouldn't http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ be a more suitable place for this question?

Comment: Here is a nice pdf for FEM triangle basis functions. It might be helpful: http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/presentations/cg_lab_fem_basis_triangle.pdf

Comment: I flagged the question. I think moderators should move it scicomp.SE

Comment: @J.D. I am not entirely convinced that scicomp is better for this question. It seems to be asking about the theory behind the FEM, which would be on topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well l I guess not,  $\phi$ may be like that on triangle T, but (with the mesh consisting of triangles with horizontal, vertical and slope=-1 edges) in the other five mesh triangles which have $\left(0,0\right)$ as a vertex, $\phi$ (I'm talking piecewise linear here) should be 1 at $\left(0,0\right)$ and disappear at the edge that is opposite to (0,0).